# A special limit-sum interversion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $l\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(u_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence converging to $l$.

Let $a_{n,k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be such that

- $\displaystyle\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\sum_{k=1}^na_{n,k}=1$.
- $\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,k}=0$
- $\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,n-k}\in\mathbb{R}$

If there existed $m$ such that $\forall k<n-m,a_{n,k}=0$, the convergence of the $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_{n,k}u_k$ to $l$ would be clear.

More generally, what hypothesis must be made on the $u_k$ so that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_{n,k}u_k$ converges to $l$ ?

Intuitively, since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,k}=0$, it seems to hold for any such sequence, but I can't find a proper proof.